# SQL Bulk Copy mapping with different column names?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlbulkcopy

We have a few columns in our tables that are not user friendly names so we change them in the actual GUI.

For example a column in the database is labeled as "IntAmt" but the user doesn't have a clue so in the program we call this column "Interest Amount".

The problem is if I use direct column mapping as shown below, then it will error as these columns do not match. There is no column in the database called "InterestAmount"

So is there a way that I can reference the correct column name in mapping with annotations or something? We are using Entity Framework as well.

```
     var connection = DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            sqc.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(sqc))
            {
                bcp.DestinationTableName = strTargetTable;

                sourceData.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(x =>
                                                                      bcp.ColumnMappings
                 .Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(x.ColumnName, x.ColumnName)));
                bcp.BatchSize = 50000;
                bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 12000;
                bcp.WriteToServer(sourceData);
            }
            sqc.Close();
        }
```

After further investigation we have column mappings stored in a table so the table looks like this

```
 TableName: ColumnMappingTable

[ColumnName]    [GuiColumnName]
  IntAmt         InterestAmount
  PrinAmt        PrincipalAmount
```

So that being said is there a way that I can map this way dynamically?
We have alot of tables and hardcoding mapping each name individually in code would take a lot of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the class that defines the db object add and IEnumerable of type SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping

```
public static IEnumerable<SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping> GetObjectNameColumnMappings()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(nameof(propertyName), "dbColumnName"),
            new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(nameof(propertyName2), "dbColumnName2")
        };
    }
```

and then call this method and set it equal to your column mappings

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(sqc))
        {
            bcp.DestinationTableName = strTargetTable;
            bcp.ColumnMappings = classInstance.GetObjectNameColumnMappings();
            bcp.BatchSize = 50000;
            bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 12000;
            bcp.WriteToServer(sourceData);
        }
```

Comment: This looks good. I have updated the question adding the mapping table that I just found we use. Is there a way to map these columns dynamically using your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TableMappings.Add()`

[Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-datatable-and-datacolumn-mappings) for reference: